# Jackson @JsonProperty annotation works recursivly?

Tags: java, annotations, jackson

I am wondering if the `@JsonProperty` annotation works recursively?

For example:

```
public class AirTravelerType {

    @JsonProperty
    protected ProfileRef profileRef;

    @JsonProperty
    protected PersonNameType personName;

    @JsonProperty
    protected List<Telephone> telephone;
```

I couldn't find any answers about this. Can somebody clarify this for me? Do I have to go to `ProfileRef` and others to mark its fields with annotations too?
Or let it as I mentioned at code snippet and this will be enough?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I investigated behavior of this.

And can say that it really ***works recursively***.

It is enough to write annotations at main model class.

Answer (score 0):

JsonProperty as exaplained [here](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.1.2/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonProperty.html) is used to specify the json property name. To know if it's work recursively, you must check the structure of your object ProfileRef .